# Clutch on 2009 Toyota Corolla S

Tags: toyota, clutch, corolla

I have a 2009 Toyota Corolla S, 5 speed manual. I started noticing a little difficulty with shifting, especially in second and fourth.  Then one day recently the clutch was just about to the floor. I had it towed in, and the mechanic supposedly kept pressing the clutch, and then it worked fine. He said it is possibility that fluid got in the lines and there was air bubbles from the master cylinder. Once he pumped the clutch, this released the fluid and the air bubbles.  My question is, is this likely a sign that the master cylinder is going out.  I don't want to take a risk with driving and the sucker goes out mid traffic or something like that. What is your suggestion?

Comment: The mech could be correct - given the high temperatures around at the moment, but if it feels "funny" again then have the master cyl changed...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!